# cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type '(Int) -> String'

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

it is normal working  function :

```
func doSomeThing(productName : String , productPrice : Double)  -> String {

        return "good jobs"
    }
```

I might thinking  function can take quantity parameter and return string

```
 func doSomeThing(productName: String , productPrice: Double) -> (Int) -> String{ 

     func totaPrice(quantity : Int) -> Double {

        return Double(quantity) * productPrice 

    }
   return "Product Name \(productName) each price is \(productPrice) , total price \(totaPrice)"
}

let totaPrice = doSomeThing(productName: "iPhone", productPrice: 649)
print(totaPrice(5))  
print(totaPrice(3))
```

But below error throwing :

> ERROR at line 14, col 11: cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type '(Int) -> String'
>      return "Product Name (productName) each price is (productPrice) , total price (totaPrice)"
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

how can fix this issue ?

**Note :I want to  do something like `Currying` function .**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function header says you are returning a closure that takes an `Int` and returns a `String`, so that is what your function should return.

Here is an example that uses all of the inputs to construct the `String`:

```
func doSomeThing(productName: String, productPrice: Double) -> (Int) -> String {
    return { n in "\(n) \(productName)s cost \(productPrice * Double(n))" }
}

let iPhone = doSomeThing(productName: "iPhone", productPrice: 649)
print(iPhone(5))
print(iPhone(2))
```

Output:

> > 5 iPhones cost 3245.0
> >     2 iPhones cost 1298.0

Comment: well ! , are there  no alternative way ?

Comment: What is your objection with this way?

Comment: i want to make it simpler and sweeter .

Comment: There isn't much wasted syntax in there.  You can use `$0` in place of `n` in the closure and get rid of `n in`, but I personally think its cleaner to explicitly name the parameter.  Does this at least capture the functionality you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're trying to return twice in one method. Instead, just have your method take 3 parameters and return a String.

```
func doSomeThing(productName : String , productPrice : Double, quantity : Int) -> String {
    let total = productPrice * Double(quantity)
    return "The total for \(productName) is \(total)"
}

doSomeThing(productName: "my product", productPrice: 1.99, quantity: 1)
```

Comment: no sir ! i want to trying like  Currying function .